# Inserting SPS NAL Units into h.264 stream

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming, h.264

I'm currently using FFmpeg to convert a Youtube livestream HLS into a H.264 UDP stream.

For it to work correctly with the device I'm using, the stream needs to have SPS NAL units inserted every so often.

I have found out that using the H.264 'main' profile, no SPS units are present.
**But when using the 'baseline' profile, one SPS unit gets inserted before each IDR NAL unit**.

Unfortunately, the 'baseline' profile causes some [video glitches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8wWI.jpg) (some patterns get repeated multiple times horizontally).

I have also tried `dump_extra=all` but still no SPS units.

Any ideas to make this work?

Here is the current command I use :

```
ffmpeg \
    -err_detect explode \
    -fflags "+genpts" -avoid_negative_ts "make_zero" \
    -loglevel warning -nostats \
    -re -i hls_url.m3u8 -segment_time 10 -hls_time 10 \
    -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -r 30 -flags +cgop -profile:v main -level 3 -bufsize 5M -minrate 5M -maxrate 5M -b:v 5M -pix_fmt yuv420p -bf 3 -s ntsc -x264opts nal-hrd=cbr:force-cfr=1:aud=1:keyint=25:open_gop=0 -aspect 16:9 -refs 3 -g 50 \
    -acodec ac3 -ar 48000 -ab 192k \
    -vf "fifo,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS" -af "afifo,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS" \
    -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb \
    -threads 2 \
    -bitrate 6M -packetsize 188 -flush_packets 0 -f mpegts "udp://multicastip:multicastport?pkt_size=1316&dscp=32"
```

Thanks!

Comment: How are you checking for NAL units? Which version of ffmpeg?

Comment: @Gyan I am using [tstools](https://github.com/kynesim/tstools). It was recommended by the maker of the device on which I'm trying to play this stream. I am using ffmpeg version N-48944-g9b069eb14e-static.